# dynamic library linkining on max mountain-lion

Tags: macos, osx-mountain-lion

I am trying to link a dynamic library (dylib) on mac mountian-lion. Nothing I try has worked.

$ gcc main.cpp -l/usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.2.4.6.dylib
  ld: library not found for -llibopencv_core.2.4.6.dylib

The library exists:

$ ls /usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.2.4.6.dylib 
  /usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.2.4.6.dylib

I get the same null result using clang.
Using otool to reveal dependencies ...

$ otool -L /usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.2.4.6.dylib
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.2.4.6.dylib:
    lib/libopencv_core.2.4.dylib (compatibility version 2.4.0, current version 2.4.6)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenCL.framework/Versions/A/OpenCL (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib (compatibility version 7.0.0, current version 56.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 169.3.0)

I am not sure what the problem is, it could be a versioning issue, I do not know.
I am probably missing something simple but essential: can anyone tell me what I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

In order to refer to a library with a filename of:

```
libMyLib.{a,so,dylib}
```

using the `-l` command line option, you use the form:

```
-lMyLib
```

So try this:

```
$ gcc main.cpp -L/usr/local/lib -lopencv_core
```

(also note that it's normally undesirable to link with a versioned dynamic library most of the time, so I have dropped it from the command line).